# Multiple BeforeDoubleClick

Tags: excel, vba

I have two BeforeDoublceClick events which i need help amalgamating, please can someone help me?

I want to amalgamate

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
   If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
   Dim last As Long
   last = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Sheet2.Range("A6:P" & last).AutoFilter
   Sheet2.Range("A6:P" & last).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
   Cancel = True
   Application.Goto Sheet2.Range("A1")
End Sub
```

and

```
If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    Dim last As Long
    last = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Range("A6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter
    Sheet1.Range("B6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    Cancel = True
    Application.Goto Sheet1.Range("B7")
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you tried on your own? I would use `Select Case` statement `Select Case Target.Column`, `Case 1: [codes here..]`, `Case 2: [codes here..]`.

Answer (score 0):

The two codes are basically the same except the goto at the end, right?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not (Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2) Then Exit Sub
    Dim last As Long
    last = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Range("A6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter
    Sheet1.Range("A6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    Cancel = True
    If Target.Column = 1 Then 
        Application.Goto Sheet1.Range("A1")
    Else
        Application.goto Sheet1.range("B7")
    End if

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah same codes but looking at different columns, and one does a filter on another sheet

Comment: I just realized i copied the wrong codes, below are the correct ones:

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
Dim last As Long
last = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2.Range("A6:P" & last).AutoFilter
Sheet2.Range("A6:P" & last).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
Cancel = True
Application.Goto Sheet2.Range("A1")
End Sub

Comment: If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub
    Dim last As Long
    last = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet1.Range("A6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter
    Sheet1.Range("B6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
    Cancel = True
    Application.Goto Sheet1.Range("B7")
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim last As Long
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        last = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Me.Range("A6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter
        Me.Range("A6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
        Cancel = True
        Application.Goto Me.Range("A1")
    ElseIf Target.Column = 2 Then
        last = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Me.Range("A6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter
        Me.Range("B6:AQ" & last).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target.Value
        Cancel = True
        Application.Goto Sheet1.Range("B7")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chris, apologies i copied the wrong codes, i have added a comment above to show that one of the codes references a separate sheet

Comment: @Jason Then edit that into your Question.   In any case, this answer is easily adapted to refer to different sheets.

Comment: Just edited, thanks Chris